# Server status dashboard using Django

Tags: python, django

I want to develop a server status dashboard which internally call ping command and show host status in red(in dashboard)if host is unreachable. As I am new to Django so just want to check if that possible via Django?

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

Django is built on Python so you can do anything that you can do in Python. This includes kicking off a process (including ping) and retrieving the results. The [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html) will probably be helpful for this. You can then pass the results to the front-end templates through the view context. If you need this to be real time you can use web sockets with [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).